# selectOneMenu produces bulleted list

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to build a web app that involves a drop down menu which, upon selecting an option, populates a table with data. I had issues, and so tried to isolate the problem by trying to recreate the [following example from the Primefaces website.](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml) I am having the following problems:

1) The selectOneMenu produces a textbox right above it in the resulting page.

2) The seelctOneMenu also produces a bulleted list of the options that are already on that select menu.

3) The ajax listener on the first select menu does not update the second menu, and does not seem to run any method in the DropdownView class.

In a nutshell, the output is unexpected, especially since I am more or less copy/pasting example code.

I am running this all on JDeveloper12c with Weblogic, JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 6.0.

Here is the code I am running, almost all of which is copy/pasted from the Primefaces site

Here's my dropdown.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<body>
<h:form>
<h:messages errorStyle="color:red" />
<p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
<p:panel header="Select a Location" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
        <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Country: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{dropdownView.country}" style="width:150px">
            <p:ajax listener="#{dropdownView.onCountryChange()}" update="city" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Country" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownView.countries}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel for="city" value="City: " />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{dropdownView.city}" style="width:150px">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select City" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{dropdownView.cities}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:separator />

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="msgs" actionListener="#{dropdownView.displayLocation()}" icon="ui-icon-check" />
</p:panel>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My DropdownView.java, which is the same code from the example site:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DropdownView implements Serializable {

private Map<String,Map<String,String>> data = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
private String country; 
private String city;  
private Map<String,String> countries;
private Map<String,String> cities;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    countries  = new HashMap<String, String>();
    countries.put("USA", "USA");
    countries.put("Germany", "Germany");
    countries.put("Brazil", "Brazil");

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("New York", "New York");
    map.put("San Francisco", "San Francisco");
    map.put("Denver", "Denver");
    data.put("USA", map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Berlin", "Berlin");
    map.put("Munich", "Munich");
    map.put("Frankfurt", "Frankfurt");
    data.put("Germany", map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Sao Paolo", "Sao Paolo");
    map.put("Rio de Janerio", "Rio de Janerio");
    map.put("Salvador", "Salvador");
    data.put("Brazil", map);
}

public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Map<String, Map<String, String>> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void setCountries(Map<String, String> countries) {
    this.countries = countries;
}

public void setCities(Map<String, String> cities) {
    this.cities = cities;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public Map<String, String> getCountries() {
    return countries;
}

public Map<String, String> getCities() {
    return cities;
}

public void onCountryChange() {
    if(country !=null && !country.equals(""))
        cities = data.get(country);
    else
        cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public void displayLocation() {
    FacesMessage msg;
    if(city != null && country != null)
        msg = new FacesMessage("Selected", city + " of " + country);
    else
        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Invalid", "City is not selected."); 

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
}
```

}

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
  <servlet>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my faces-config.xml:

```
    <faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the HTML `<body>` tag by the JSF `<h:body>` tag. Probably even more important, add an `<h:head />` line. It may be empty, but it's important because that's where the JavaScript and CSS files are added.

BTW, the problems you describe indicate that these files are missing. You see how the selectOneMenu is constructed from the HTML building blocks, but without the CSS and JavaScript glue code.